Exercise similar to the ballot box model
Consider the following problem
A box contains 10 bulbs of which 6 are new and 4 are used, 4 bulbs are selected at random without replacement until a used one is removed. I want to determine the probability that exactly 3 bulbs need to be selected to obtain the first used bulb.
Let A:3 bulbs are randomly selected, B:The i-th bulb is used, I think what we want to determine is:
$$P(B_{1}|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B_{1})}{P(A)}$$
Noting that $P(A)=\frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}$, but what about the intersection, here I want to calculate the probability that three are taken at random, and among them the first one is used, I have thought of something like:
$$P(A \cap B_1)=\frac{\binom{4}{3} \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$
But I'm not entirely convinced, I feel I leave cases out when calculating for intersection, any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

The phrasing is odd.  I believe it is asking for a conditional probability.  Specifically, it is saying "given that one of the first four draws is a bad bulb, what is the probability that the third draw is the first bad one?"  But, as I say, the phrasing is odd so I'm not sure my interpretation is what was intended.

If you need to express it in terms of conditional probabilities, then using the symbols N for drawing new and U for used bulbs, indexed as a sequence, we need to find the probability
$P(N_1).P(N2 | N_1).P(U_3 | N_1,N_2)$
$= \dfrac{6}{10}\dfrac{5}{9}\dfrac{4}{8} = \dfrac{1}{6}$
An impoetant  thing to remember (beginners often make mistakes on this) is that when an $\;$ ordered $\;$ sequence (i.e. a $\;$ specified $\;$ sequence) is needed, the general multiplication rule works well, whereas if an $\;$ unordered $\;$ sequence (i.e. all possible sequences) is needed, the hypergeometric formula suits best.
Here, for example, if we used the hypergeometric formula, viz $Pr =\dfrac{\binom62\binom41}{\binom{10}3}$, we would need to divide the result by $3$ to arrive at the particular sequence needed

The problem is asking for the probability of a specific sequence of three events:

The first bulb selected is new.  The probability of this is $\frac{6}{10} = \frac{3}{5}$.  Afterwards, the box contains 5 new bulbs and 4 used ones.
The second bulb selected is also new.  The probability is $\frac{5}{9}$.  Afterwards, the box contains 4 new bulbs and 4 used bulbs.
The third bulb selected is used.  The probability is $\frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$.

So the probability of the overall sequence is $\frac{3}{5} \times \frac{5}{9} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$.

This is the probability of what I call the intersection probability?, by the way thanks for your contribution.


Let A:3 bulbs are randomly selected, B:The i-th bulb is used, I think what we want to determine is:


$$P(B_{1}|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B_{1})}{P(A)}$$

In my opinion, this type of problem doesn't really lend itself to analysis based on conditional probability events.  Instead, in my opinion, the easiest approach might be decided as follows:

When the numbers are small, the probability oriented approach taken by the answer of Dan is simple and clear.

When the numbers are large, it is generally best to use a combinatorics-oriented approach to attack the probability problem.


By way of illustration, I will first use the combinatorics-oriented approach on your specific problem.  Then, for illustrative purposes, I will use the combinatorics-oriented approach for an alternate problem, where there are 50 bulbs of which 30 are new, and 20 are used, and you want to know the probability that the 17-th bulb taken is the first used bulb.

In the original problem, for a satisfying sequence, two things must happen:

The first 2 bulbs taken must be new.

Then, the next bulb taken, must be used.


The probability will be expressed as
$$\frac{N_1}{D_1} \times \frac{N_2}{D_2},~$$
where

$N_1~$ represents the number of equally likely ways that the first 2 bulbs taken are new. 
Since there are $~6~$ bulbs to begin with, $~\displaystyle N_1 = \binom{6}{2} = 15.$ 
That is, $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2}~$ represents the number of ways of selecting 2 bulbs from the 6 new bulbs, sampling without replacement, where order of selection is deemed irrelevant.

Similarly, $~\displaystyle D_1 = \binom{10}{2} = 45.$

At this point, there are now $~8~$ bulbs left, of which $~4~$ are new, and $~4~$ are used.

So, $~\displaystyle N_2 = \binom{4}{1} = 4, ~~$ and $~~\displaystyle D_2 = \binom{8}{1} = 8.$


Therefore, the probability is
$$\frac{N_1}{D_1} \times \frac{N_2}{D_2} = \frac{15}{45} \times \frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{6}.$$
So, the above approach represents a model that simplifies the attack on the alternate problem.
In the alternate problem, with $~50~$ bulbs, of which $~30~$ are new, and $~20~$ are used, and where you want to know the probability that the $~17$-th bulb taken was the first used bulb, two events must happen:

The first $~16~$ bulbs taken must be new.

Then, the next bulb taken must be used.


Again, computing the probability as
$$\frac{N_1}{D_1} \times \frac{N_2}{D_2},$$
you have that:

$\displaystyle N_1 = \binom{30}{16}.$

$\displaystyle D_1 = \binom{50}{16}.$

At this point, you have $~34~$ bulbs remaining, of which $~14~$ are new and $~20~$ are used.  So:

$\displaystyle N_2 = \binom{20}{1}.$

$\displaystyle D_2 = \binom{34}{1}.$


Therefore, in this alternate problem, the probability is
$$\frac{N_1}{D_1} \times \frac{N_2}{D_2} = \frac{\binom{30}{16}}{\binom{50}{16}} \times \frac{\binom{20}{1}}{\binom{34}{1}}.$$

To elaborate on the comments:  I believe the problem to be very oddly phrased.  What does "4 bulbs are selected at random without replacement until a used one is removed" mean?  I believe (but am not sure) that it is asking for a conditional probability.  That is, I think we are asked "suppose we draw bulbs one at a time, stopping when you get the first bad one.  Given that you are told that it takes no more than $4$ draws, what is the probability that the third draw was the first bad one?"
To answer that question: The compliment of taking no more than $4$ draws to find the first bad one is drawing four good ones in a row.  Thus the probability that it takes no more than $4$ draws is $$1-\binom 64\Big / \binom {10}4=\frac {13}{14}$$
Now, the only path we actually care about is $GGB$ (two good bulbs followed by a bad).  The probability of that sequence is $$\frac 6{10}\times \frac 59\times \frac 48=\frac 16$$
Thus the conditional probability sought by (my interpretation of) the question is the quotient $$\frac 16\Big / \frac {13}{14}=\boxed {\frac 7{39}}$$
